# Laplacian of spherical coordinate

Tags: calculus, laplacian

In Strauss PDE textbook, he derived the formula of Laplaican of spherical coordinate as follows:

> changing $(x,y,z)$ to $(r,\theta,\phi)$: Use te notation $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} = \sqrt{s^2+z^2}$, $s = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, $x = s\cos\phi$, $y = s\sin\phi$, $z = r\cos\theta$, $s =r\sin\theta$. By the two-dimensional Laplace calculation, we have both
> $$u_{zz}+u_{ss} = u_{rr}+{1\over r}u_r+{1\over r^2}u_{\theta\theta}$$
> and
> $$u_{xx}+u_{yy} = u_{ss} + {1\over s}u_{s}+{1\over s^2}u_{\phi,\phi}.$$
> We add these two equations, and cancel $u_{ss}$, to get
> $$u_{xx}+u_{yy}+u_{zz} = u_{rr}+{1\over r}u_r+{1\over r^2}u_{\theta\theta}+{1\over s}u_s+{1\over s^2}u_{\phi\phi}.$$
> In the last term we substitute $s^2 = r^2\sin^2\theta$ and in the next-to-last term
> \begin{align*}
> u_s & = {\partial u\over\partial s} = u_r{\partial r\over\partial s}+u_\theta{\partial\theta\over\partial s}+u_\phi{\partial\phi\over\partial s}\\
> & = u_r{s\over r}+u_{\theta}{\cos\theta\over r}.\\
> \end{align*}

I don't understand the last equality. Why ${\partial r\over\partial s} = {s\over r}$ and ${\partial\theta\over\partial s} = {\cos\theta\over r}$? From $s = r\sin\theta$, I can get
$$1 = {\partial r\over\partial s}\sin\theta+r\cos\theta{\partial\theta\over\partial s}.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the definitions
$$r^2 = s^2 + z^2.$$
Implicit differentiation wrt $s$ gives
$$ 2r \frac{\partial r}{\partial s} = 2s + 0$$
since $\partial z/\partial s = 0$, and this rearranges to the claim.

Comment: there was I think a comment on why $\del z/\del s = 0$. This is from definitions- $r$ is treated as a function of $s,z$ (and technically, of $\phi$), and partial differentiation wrt s means to hold all other variables ( that means $z,\phi$) constant and differentiate.